# Google Cloud Run for Anthos: Using Managed SSL

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

**[ Note to reader: This is a long question, please bear with me ]**

I've been messing with Cloud Run for Anthos as a side project, and have got a service up and running on http (not https) -- it performs as expected, scaling up and scaling down as traffic requires.

I now want to add SSL to it, so traffic comes on SSL only. And I've been banging my head against a wall on this trying to get it to work. Mainly centering on [this link](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/run/docs/managed-tls)

I have setup the cluster default domain (it shows up on the Cloud Run for Anthos page) and my service is accessible via http://myservice.mynamespace.mydomain.com (not my real domain, obviously)

I've patched the knative configs, enabling autoTLS and setting mydomain as needed:

```
kubectl patch configmap config-domain --namespace knative-serving --patch '{"data": {"mydomain.com": ""}}'
kubectl patch configmap config-domain --namespace knative-serving --patch '{"data": {"nip.io": null}}'
kubectl patch configmap config-domainmapping --namespace knative-serving --patch '{"data": {"autoTLS": "Enabled"}}'
kubectl patch configmap config-network --namespace knative-serving --patch '{"data": {"autoTLS": "Enabled"}}'
kubectl patch configmap config-network --namespace knative-serving --patch '{"data": {"httpProtocol": "Enabled"}}'
```

The documentation talks about using gcloud domain mapping:

```
gcloud run domain-mappings describe --domain DOMAIN
```

Yet, this only is available on beta

```
ERROR: (gcloud.run.domain-mappings.describe) This command group is in beta for fully managed Cloud Run; use `gcloud beta run domain-mappings`.
```

Using beta, however, also fails

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.domain-mappings.describe) NOT_FOUND: Resource 'mydomain.com' of kind 'DOMAIN_MAPPING' in region 'europe-west2' in project 'my-project' does not exist
```

Making my cluster zonal or regional makes no difference.

The documentation also mentions using `kcert`

```
kubectl get kcert
```

Yet this does not show anything until after I have deployed my service.

```
$ kubectl get kcert --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE   NAME                                         READY   REASON
default     route-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And this NEVER shows ready. Trying to hit http://myservice.mynamespace.mydomain.com remains fine, but hitting https://myservice.mynamespace.mydomain.com returns:

```
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to myservice.mynamespace.mydomain.com:443
```

Can anyone guide me into why I can't get SSL working on this?

Related question -- is it possible to use the already-configured cert-manager cluster issuer instead? Such as described [here](https://knative.dev/docs/serving/using-auto-tls/#automatic-tls-provision-mode)?

Comment: It is not possible to use Cloud Run domain mappings in the following [regions](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains#limitations). Can you try by mapping your domain to another region? Ex: europe-west1

Comment: Does it not work on zonal, out of curiosity?

Comment: What does **zonal** mean in your last comment?

Comment: Zonal meaning things like europe-west2-a, europe-west2-b and europe-west2-c -- you can set up clusters in a single zone, or across a region such as europe-west2 (which balances nodes across all the zones in the region). I tried a regional cluster in europe-west-2 which didn't work, as @ChandraKiranPasumarti explained, because it's on a zone that doesn't support it. But I'm wondering whether  it would work in a zonal situation, instead of regional

Comment: If a region does not support a feature, that means a zone will not either. The limitation is not zonal - it is regional.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley , I'll try on a different zone and region

Comment: @Blendor Fox, Have you tried by mapping your domain to other region? Is the issue resolved or still facing any issues?

Comment: @ChandraKiranPasumarti I haven't yet tried other region, but I intend to when I can get a chance.